# SwiftUI: How can i allow user to drag filled image in a TabView page while keep change page gesture

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-image

I'm using TabView with page style to show a list of Images:

Reader.swift

```
...
TabView(selection: self.$archivePageModel.currentIndex) {
    ForEach(pageOrder(totalPage: archivePageModel.pages.count), id: \.self) { index in
        PageImage(id: archivePageModel.pages[index], geometrySize: geometry.size).tag(index)
    }
}
...
```

PageImage.swift

```
...
Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl)!)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
...
```

Sometimes, the page image could be a single width image, thus I want to give user the option to "fit height" of the image, so I tried to use `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` to fill the whole page with image. I then added more modifier to PageImage so the filled image could show from start and user could drag the image

PageImage.swift - updated

```
...
let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl)!
let imageWidth = uiImage.size.width / uiImage.size.height * geometrySize.height
Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl)!)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: geometrySize.width, alignment: .leading)
    .draggableAndZoomable(contentSize: CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: geometrySize.height), viewWidth: geometrySize.width)
...
```

DraggableAndZoomableView.swift

```
...
@GestureState private var offsetState = CGSize.zero
@State private var offset = CGSize.zero

content
    .offset(x: ...compute x axis..., y: ...compute y axis...)
    .gesture(dragGesture)


var dragGesture: some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        ...logic of drag image...
}
...
```

It all works. However, my custom `dragGesture` here overrides the normal `TabView` drag gesture to change pages.

Is there a way to keep my custom `dragGesture` while at the same time, trigger the `TabView` drag gesture to switch page if user dragged to the edge of the image?

Thanks.